# Lerp speed or lerp time

Tags: c#, unity, mathematics, lerp

Am I right about the fact that lerping can be done over a set period of time *or* at a speed which will continue until the target is reached?

How are the formulas for the two? Is it something like this?

LERP at speed:

```
// does not use start value but instead current value
newValue= Lerp (currentValue, targetValue, Time.deltaTime * speed);
```

LERP over set duration:

```
//uses startValue and calculates the progress percentage over time
var newValue = Lerp (startValue, targetvalue, percentage);
percentage= (Time.time - startTime) / duration;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using speed (particularly variable speed) until some target position (especially if the target can move) is reached, it's not really LERPing.  That's more akin to steering.

If you do have a fixed distance to cover and a fixed speed then you can easily calculate the time to LERP over.  Remember the units of `speed` are units of `distance` over units of `time`.  Assuming your fundamental units agree (e.g. not mixing miles-per-hour with meters and seconds) then you can get the time to LERP over with a teensy bit of algebra, giving you `time=distance/speed`.